# SQL Injection and addSlashes

Tags: php, mysql, csv, sql-injection

In this verbatim mysql based code below, a CSV file is parsed and a mySQL table is created on the fly. *I just run into it at* -> http://www.johnboy.com/blog/tutorial-import-a-csv-file-using-php-and-mysql

As you see, they are using addslashes.

This code saves me time but before I start using it (in a WordPress environment with 5.3 where mysqli or PDO is not available), I'd like to pick your brains if it's safe for what its doing.

It all comes down to addslashes. I'm curious as to why they did not go for my_real_escape_string.

```
//connect to the database
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
mysql_select_db("mydatabase",$connect); //select the table
//

if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) {

    //get the csv file
    $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name];
    $handle = fopen($file,"r");

    //loop through the csv file and insert into database
    do {
        if ($data[0]) {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO contacts (contact_first, contact_last, contact_email) VALUES
                (
                    '".addslashes($data[0])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[1])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[2])."'
                )
            ");
        }
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"));
    //

    //redirect
    header('Location: import.php?success=1'); die;

}
```

Comment: Why are you still using `mysql_query`? Use mysqli or PDO

Comment: please re-read the question. I just added the why.

Comment: PHP 5.3 has [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php) and [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php) builtin, so you could easily use at least mysqli, even if PDO should be disabled.

Comment: Interesting. Could you comment on this please? http://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/04/07/mysql-in-wordpress-3-9/

Comment: You don't use `$wpdp`, so where's the problem to use mysqli for this piece of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PDO` and `MySQLi` have built-in functions for creating prepared queries which let you use quotes and apostrophes without any problems.

**But** for your question: Replace `addslashes()` with `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

`addslashes` can be passed by very easily and is not safe at all.

[Read this article for more info about bypassing `addslashes`.](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string)

Comment: How can `addslashes` be passed by very easily?

Comment: Quite right; I don't understand the -1. `mysql_real_escape_string()` is really the way to go if you are restricted to the old mySQL extension.

Comment: And, additionally: If I have two functions, of which one does *exactly* what I want (escape the stuff I want to put into the database) and the other does "something like what I want" (add slashes where they may or may not be appropriate), which one would I choose? The former, exactly. So I don't even see the need for even thinking about `addslashes`...

Comment: thanks for participating.. quickly.. what do you guys mean by `-1` or `-2`?. I don't get that convention.

Comment: @AverageJoe 2 People downvoted my answer without giving any reason/comment for it.

Comment: To bypass `addslashes` a certain set of conditions is required. Most importantly GBK must be used, which is probably quite rare. This is rather an edge case. So the generalization “`addslashes` can be passed by very easily” is rather misleading.

Comment: @glglgl Precisely, of course the 1st would be the best option.

Comment: @Gumbo "Rare" is still a chance.

Comment: Houssni, they downvoted your answer cause they like the exercise. It feels great. I accepted your answer. Thank you for Chris' linkl

Answer (score 0):

[`addslashes`](http://php.net/addslashes) escapes certain characters:

> These characters are single quote (`'`), double quote (`"`), backslash (`\`) and NUL (the NULL byte).

These are also crucial in [MySQL string literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-literals.html) as they are either used as delimiters or introduce an escape sequence. This is probably why `addslashes` was chosen in the example.

However, `addslashes` does only work on bytes while [MySQL does also support a variety of character sets/encodings](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-charsets.html), of which some are multi-byte. `addslashes` fails on multi-byte character encodings while [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) takes the current character encoding into account:

> Escapes special characters in the *unescaped_string*, taking into account the current character set of the connection so that it is safe to place it in a `mysql_query()`. If binary data is to be inserted, this function must be used.

And there are [actual cases where `addslashes` does not sufficiently escapes data due to some multi-byte character encoding](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string). That’s why `addslashes` should not be used to escape strings for being used in a MySQL string literal. It’s simply not meant for that.